# Variable naming in the interactive shell, mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a web app, that accepts parameters that then go on to create a collection in mongodb. I'm currently doing some testing and using the interactive shell to find if the read and writes are correct. If I use a some character everything works correctly. When I use something with a - or numbers, I get an error. eg:

```
> db.getCollectionNames();
[ "1", "2", "deviceslist", "system.indexes" ]
> db.1.find()
Sun Oct  9 22:58:22 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (shell):1
>
```

Is there something I am missing or does mongodb just dont accept these things??

I've tried combinations of

db.'1'.find()
db."1".find()

and none seem to work.

Help please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access the collection in the following way:

```
db[1].find();
```

or

```
db['1'].find();
```

but i don't know, if there are any negative side-effects when naming a collection like so.

Comment: > db.[1].find();
    Sun Oct  9 23:25:40 SyntaxError: missing name after . operator    (shell):1
    > db.['1'].find();
    Sun Oct  9 23:25:46 SyntaxError: missing name after . operator (shell):1
    > db.["1"].find();
    Sun Oct  9 23:25:55 SyntaxError: missing name after . operator (shell):1
    >

Comment: still syntax error. The other option is to make it so the user can only name it a certain way, which is hard..

Comment: you have a dot in your notation. it is db[1] *not* db.[1]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with giving a collection a numeric name except that JavaScript parsing will require you to use the bracket notation as harald's answer suggested.

db.one.find()  // no issues

db['1'].find() // can't type db.1.find(), JavaScript parsing won't accept it